# Codeigniter 3.0 query bug

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Duplicate this table: **User_Posts**

```
ID     | Upvotes | Downvotes | CAT  |
___________________________________
42134  |   5     |      3    | Blogs|
------------------------------------
12342  |   7     |      1    | Blogs|
-------------------------------------
19344  |   6     |      2    | Blogs|
------------------------------------
```

I need to get the rank of an item within it's category. Therefore ID: 19344 will have Rank position 2, with 4 upvotes, behind 12342 with 6 upvotes. Rank is determined by (upvotes-downvotes) count within it's category.

So I wrote this MySQL query.

```
SELECT rank FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM User_Posts where CAT= 'Blogs' order by 
(Upvotes-Downvotes) DESC) d, 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) t2 WHERE POST_ID = '19344'
```

**Returns to me (Rank = 2) when run directly in mysql.** This is the correct result

However when I try to build it out through code-igniter's query builder I get the

```
$table = 'User_Posts'; 
$CAT= 'Blogs'; 
$POST_ID = '19344';

 $sql = "SELECT rank FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS
 rank FROM $table where CAT= ? 
 order by (Upvotes-Downvotes) DESC) d, 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) t2 WHERE POST_ID= ?";

$query= $this->db->query($sql, array($CAT,$POST_ID))->row_array();
```

**returns to me an empty result: array(rank=>);**

so then my question is... *but why*?

I will also accept an answer will an alternative way to run this query from code-igniters query builder, but ideally I would like to know why this thing is broken.

Comment: Can't you simplify the SQL to `SELECT (Upvotes - Downvotes) AS rank FROM User_Posts WHERE CAT = 'Blogs' AND POST_ID = 19344;`? Seems like that would be trivial to implement in CI's query builder too.

Comment: @quickshiftin rank is not the number of (upvotes-downvotes) but it is the position of the item with respect to each other item in the same category.

Comment: Ok, how do you account for ties in (upvotes-downvotes) for a given category?

Comment: @quickshiftin good question for now it will just be the same rank

Comment: I might use a combination of the query log and a debugger to track it down. Another option would be looking at an alternative query that code igniter can grock. Maybe it doesn't like the variable assignment in your current query.

Comment: Just bypass the prepared statements(run it hardcoded) for testing,I suspect there is a problem there.

Comment: @mihai ran it without the bindings same result

Comment: @MsYvette - No, the table was added to the string.  It could not be done by binding because it would get quotes around it.

Comment: If there were a syntax error in the query, would Codeigniter have informed you?

Comment: @rickJames yes it would have, there is no syntax error otherwise i would not get a result, but I am getting returned an array with array('rank' =>)

Comment: I suggest you to print your query and see what CI is building query `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a similar issue in the past, turns out I had to initialize the variable with a separate query first, I am not sure if this is still the case, but give it a try anyway.

```
//initialize the variable, before running the ranking query.
$this->db->query('SELECT 0 INTO @rownum');
$query= $this->db->query($sql, array($CAT,$POST_ID))->row_array();
```

Comment: This was the solution you have to init the variable. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Edward ...but you already knew this! You just did it in the wrong place in your query. N.B. If you do it this way, you can remove `, (SELECT @rownum:=0) t2` from your query.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly I don't know why your code is not working. I wrote another solution it will work. Try below code.

```
$select="FIND_IN_SET( (upvote-downvote), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( (upvote-downvote) ORDER BY (upvote-downvote) DESC ) as total FROM (User_Posts))) as rank";
$this->db->select($select,FALSE);
$this->db->from('(User_Posts)',FALSE);
$this->db->where('ID',19344);
$this->db->where('CAT','Blogs');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a Stored Function to do the query.  Then have Codeigniter merely do

```
query("SELECT PostRank(?,?)", $CAT, $POST_ID);
```

Restriction:  Since you cannot do `PREPARE` inside a Stored Function, this function will necessarily be specific to one table, `User_Posts`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the problem, but I'd be initialising `@rownum` in the subquery:

```
SELECT rank 
  FROM (
     SELECT *, 
            @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank 
       FROM $table
       JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) init
      WHERE CAT= ? 
   ORDER BY (Upvotes-Downvotes) DESC
       ) d 
 WHERE post_id = ?
```

Otherwise I'd be worried that `@rownum` is undefined (`NULL`) and stays that way while `rank` is calculated (`NULL + 1 = NULL`), only being assigned the value of `0` afterwards. Thus `rank` is returned as `NULL` and you get `['rank'=>]`.

Running this again in a constant connection (directly in MySQL) would then give you the correct result as `@rownum` would start from the value `0` from the previous query and `rank` would be calculated correctly.

I'm guessing codeigniter starts a new connection/transaction each time the query is run and `@rownum` starts at `NULL` each time, giving `['rank'=>]`.